# how to create bottom nav bar with dynamic floating action button with good animation flutter?

Tags: flutter, floating-action-button, flutter-bottomnavigation

I would like to create a custom bottom nav bar with a changed floating action button like this:

[image]

and when change tab it will be like this with nice and ease animation:

[image]

any suggestions how we can built it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for this design

**ff_navigation_bar** package [here](https://pub.dev/packages/ff_navigation_bar)

**motion_tab_bar** package [here](https://pub.dev/packages/motion_tab_bar)

**fancy_bottom_navigation** [here](https://pub.dev/packages/fancy_bottom_navigation) hope its helpful to you.

for more packages for bottom navigation bar go [here](https://fluttergems.dev/bottom-navigation-bar/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the [Convex_bottom_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/convex_bottom_bar)

And here all [bottom_nav_bar](https://pub.dev/packages?q=bottom%20navigation%20bar&sort=like) package

```
import 'package:convex_bottom_bar/convex_bottom_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => _State();
}

class _State extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: "/",
      routes: {
        "/": (_) => HelloConvexAppBar(),
        "/bar": (BuildContext context) => Container(),
        "/custom": (BuildContext context) => Container(),
        "/fab": (BuildContext context) => Container(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class HelloConvexAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Hello ConvexAppBar')),
      body: Center(
          child: TextButton(
            child: Text('Click to show full example'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/bar'),
          )),
      bottomNavigationBar: ConvexAppBar(
        style: TabStyle.react,
        items: [
          TabItem(icon: Icons.list),
          TabItem(icon: Icons.calendar_today),
          TabItem(icon: Icons.assessment),
        ],
        initialActiveIndex: 1,
        onTap: (int i) => print('click index=$i'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```